# MySql-Update: Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I am trying to performing update operation on value which meet certain criteria. My tables `CAPD, CAMP, CAD`. But I get error of

> Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'CAPD' for update in
>   FROM clause

```
UPDATE CAPD SET CAPD.Is_Active = 1
WHERE CAPD.Per_Id IN (
    SELECT CAMP.Id

    FROM CAMP 

    INNER JOIN CAPD ON (
        CAPD.Per_Id = CAMP.Id 
        AND CAPD.Is_Active = 0 
    ) 
    INNER JOIN CAD ON (
        CAD.Id = CAPD.Deploy_Id 
        AND BINARY CAD.Access_Id = "486579446F6E277-4436F6E7665727449742E2E4C-4F4C203A5020584F586F"
    ) 

    WHERE CAMP.Serial = "ABC1230071"
)
```

Comment: i did, that's why i deleted the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You cannot use the target table which you are updating inside the
>   subquery. You need to use the JOIN in case you want to use it -- First
>   answer by @Rahul Tripathi

You have to try this query then you need to set `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES`

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;

UPDATE CAPD 
INNER JOIN CAD ON ( CAD.Id = CAPD.Deploy_Id) 

SET CAPD.Is_Active = 1

WHERE CAPD.Per_Id IN (
 SELECT CAMP.Id 
    FROM CAMP 
    WHERE CAMP.Serial = "ABC1230071"
)

AND  BINARY CAD.Access_Id = "486579446F6E277-4436F6E7665727449742E2E4C-4F4C203A5020584F586F";

SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1;
```

Comment: Let me try this query first

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the target table which you are updating inside the subquery. You need to use the `JOIN` in case you want to use it. Try like this:

```
UPDATE CAPD 
INNER JOIN CAD ON ( CAD.Id = CAPD.Deploy_Id) 
SET CAPD.Is_Active = 1
WHERE CAPD.Per_Id IN (SELECT CAMP.Id 
FROM CAMP 
WHERE CAMP.Serial = "ABC1230071" ) 
and CAD.Access_Id = "486579446F6E277-4436F6E7665727449742E2E4C-4F4C203A5020584F586F"
and CAPD.Is_Active = 0
```

Comment: This query update only single row ... But I have many which have to update as well